# bash's strange behavior on a function named "@"

Tags: bash

Today I found a strange behavior in bash.

When you define function named "@" in an interactive shell using this syntax:

```
$ function @() { echo foo; }
```

it (of course) defines a function named "@".

However, in specific situations, e.g. in tmux session or in virtual console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), this defines a function named "@()".
I couldn't find any difference in these environments (output of `echo $-` was `himBH`). Besides, `function @ { echo bar; }` doesn't have this trap and defines "@" in both situations. I couldn't find any document that says @ is a special symbol in bash.

Does anyone know anything about this?
I confirmed these on vanilla Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" is caused by the shell option `extglob`.

#### extglob: on

```
[STEP 100] # echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release
[STEP 101] # shopt -s extglob 
[STEP 102] # echo @()
@()
[STEP 103] # function @() { shopt extglob; }
[STEP 104] # @()
extglob         on
[STEP 105] # unset -f @()
[STEP 106] #
```

When `extglob on`, I guess Bash's syntax parser would treat `@()` as a whole (because it looks like a valid *extended glob pattern*) and pass it to the `function` command as **one single** paramter so `function @() {}` is in the `function NAME {}` syntax and so `@()` is the function name.

#### extglob: off

```
[STEP 107] # shopt -u extglob 
[STEP 108] # echo @()
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[STEP 109] # function @() { shopt extglob; }
[STEP 110] # @
extglob         off
[STEP 111] #
```

When `extglob off`, `function @() {}` is in the `function NAME() {}` syntax and so `@` is the function name.

---

Chet's [explanation](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-03/msg00222.html) in the *bug-bash* mailing list:

> A shell function name is a WORD, though POSIX mode restricts it to a NAME.
>   It does not undergo any expansions.
>
> When `extglob` is enabled, `@()` is part of a WORD, since it's a valid extended
>   glob pattern, and glob patterns can be contained in a WORD.  This is one
>   example of the differing parser behavior when `extglob` is enabled. So
>   there's no problem with defining a function named `@()`.  When `extglob` is
>   not enabled, `@()` is not a valid pattern, and the parens are parsed as
>   separate operators. In this case they happen to make sense, and define a
>   function named `@`.
>
> When you try to execute it, since it's not quoted, it undergoes the normal
>   word expansions, one of which is filename generation.  It doesn't match
>   anything, so it's left intact, and the function named `@()` executes.  When
>   `nullglob` is enabled, the pattern still doesn't match anything, and is
>   removed. This leaves you with the null command, which also executes, and
>   returns a status of 0.

Comment: Thanks, what a perfect answer. Yes, the difference was `extglob`. But still I'm curious where this difference came from...

Comment: added Chet's explanation in the bug-bash maillist.

Answer (score 1):

In bash there are two scenarios (that I'm aware of) where the "@" symbol is used. The first is when dealing with parameters:

```
function mytest() {
    echo $@
}
mytest "param1" "param2" "param3"
```

The second is when dealing with arrays:

```
declare myarray=("item1" "item2")
printf "${myarray[@]}\n"
```

While `function @() {}` may work as a function name, it should be considered bad practice. Give functions a practical name. Something that tells the user what it's purpose is.